# Can cause and effect be used in the same tense?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, tense-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

Are these tenses used correctly in these sentences?

> The prospects of self-isolation and the implementation of quarantine have brought about the need to accumulate food supplies, which has resulted in long queues and empty showcases in supermarkets.
>
> The epidemic has set new consumption rules, which has deprived the society of the traditional types of consumption and the motives behind it.

I have a cause-effect relation in both sentences, but as the both parts refer to the recent events connected with the corona, I feel like I have to use present perfect. Could you please help me?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the same tense in the same sentence?

Comment: It's the matter of using the same tense when I have a cause and effect relation in the sentence, i.e. one actions follows another, but they are both connected to the present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the cause and effect are both conditions extending right up to the present time, the present perfect is correct for both, so the tenses in both sentences seem correct.
 As a matter of style, I think you could vary the verb forms by substituting "resulting" for "which has resulted" in the first sentence, and "depriving" for "which has deprived" in the second. That wouldn't change the meaning of either sentence.